# computing the actual address from assembly in cmp

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, cpu-registers, cmp

I am using gdb in order to debug my code, still a beginner
I wanted to know how to get the actual address
For example, given the following assembly code:
    cmp %eax, 0x4(%rbp,%rbx,4)

I want to know what is being compared with %eax, in other words i want to know what is in: 0x4(%rbp,%rbx,4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know at&t syntax, switch gdb to intel syntax using `set disassembly-flavor intel`. Then you will see this expression is really `rbp+rbx*4+4`. Then read gdb help and you will find the `x` (examine memory) command and that you can access registers using `$` prefix. Putting all this together, you should type `x $rbp+$rbx*4+4` to see the contents.